# Edges of the bitmap got distorted when saving

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a blank image and on that i put some stickers then i want to save the images. But when i save the image i find that its edges got distorted.

EDIT : there is also a problem. may be a trade off with edge distortion with sticker position.. it is chaning the position of the sticker. when i use 4000*2250 black image as background image and when i use 2000*1500 as background image it doesn't create any problem with the position but chg the resoulation of the image.

this is the pic before saving inside the app :

[image: normal picture]

this is the pic after saving in my sd card:

[image: edge got distorted]

Here is my bitmap saving code:

```
public Bitmap saveCurrentBitmap() {
        EditActivity act = (EditActivity) mContext;

        Bitmap origRawImage = act.getRawBitmap();
        // copy to mutable
        Bitmap rawImage = origRawImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        if (rawImage == null)
            return null;

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(rawImage);

        // get scale factor
        RectF scaledImg = act.getImageView().getInnerBitmapSize();
        float scale = rawImage.getWidth() / scaledImg.width();

        List<DraggableBitmap> stampList = act.getImageView().getOverlayList();
        if (stampList.size() > 0) {
            Enumeration<DraggableBitmap> e = Collections.enumeration(stampList);
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                DraggableBitmap dBmp = (DraggableBitmap) e.nextElement();

                Matrix finalMtx = new Matrix();

                // calculate margin and move back
                Matrix marginMtx = dBmp.getMarginMatrix();
                float[] moveArr = new float[9];
                marginMtx.getValues(moveArr);
                float x = -(moveArr[0]);
                float y = -(moveArr[3]);
                Matrix moveBackMtx = new Matrix();
                moveBackMtx.postTranslate(x, y);

                // current manipulate matrix (rotate, zoom, move..)
                Matrix manipulateMtx = dBmp.getCurrentMatrix();
                Matrix scaleMtx = new Matrix();

                // scale to original size
                scaleMtx.postScale(scale, scale, 0, 0);

                manipulateMtx = (manipulateMtx == null) ? new Matrix() : manipulateMtx;
                finalMtx.postConcat(manipulateMtx);
                finalMtx.postConcat(moveBackMtx);
                finalMtx.postConcat(scaleMtx);
                canvas.drawBitmap(dBmp.mBitmap, finalMtx, null);
            }
        }

        return rawImage;
    }
```

and this is the code that calling the savebitmap

```
private void saveImage() {
        Bitmap bmpToSave = mActivityHelper.saveCurrentBitmap();
        this.getBaseApplication().setRawBitmap(bmpToSave);
        savedImagePath = SaveToStorageUtil.save(bmpToSave, this);
        ImageScannerAdapter adapter = new ImageScannerAdapter(this);
        adapter.scanImage(savedImagePath);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but i see no edges that are distorted. I only see that the second image is smaller and less detailed. And what is the question?

Comment: `saveCurrentBitmap()` is not saving a bitmap. It only returns a Bitmap.

Comment: saveimage code is uploaded  and there is distortion if you look carefully @greenapps

Comment: There is no logic in how you describe your problem. Why posting code that constructs an image? You post losts of code of which we cannot see what it does. You forget to tell where the first picture is in in your code. Also what is the second picture? You did not react on my observation that the second image is smaller. Please describe a reproducable problem.

Comment: Sorry not to mention that .in the second picture i have cropped it using snipping tool in windows.That's why it gets smaller but if you observe it carefully you can find that it gets somehow distorted.
I have managed solving this problem but there raise another .Now the sticker displaced. It gets shifted to right by some pixels. I guess there is some matrix calculation error.cant figure 
P.S. Here first image is when i am in the dashboard editing the picture by putting some stickers on it. And when i save the dashboard picture it stores in my sd card from where i have found the second picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawBitmap(dBmp.mBitmap, finalMtx, p);
```